Access a C++ struct from Java using JNA
I'm new to JNA and trying to put together a very minimal proof-of-concept for accessing structs from a C++ shared library. Unfortunately, it doesn't run and I cannot figure it out.
Here's my code:
Main.java:
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Structure.FieldOrder;

public class Main {
    public interface MyCppLibrary extends Library {
        MyCppLibrary INSTANCE = (MyCppLibrary) Native.load("mycpplib", MyCppLibrary.class);

        @FieldOrder({"x", "y"})
        class MyStruct extends Structure {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        MyStruct getStruct();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCppLibrary lib = MyCppLibrary.INSTANCE;
        MyCppLibrary.MyStruct myStruct = lib.getStruct();

        System.out.println("x: " + myStruct.x);
        System.out.println("y: " + myStruct.y);
    }
}

MyStruct.cpp:
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    double y;
};

extern "C" {
    MyStruct* getStruct() {
        return new MyStruct{10, 20.5};
    }
}

I compile the C++ code into a shared library (using WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04):
g++ -v -shared -o libmycpplib.so my_struct.cpp

But when I run the Java class (of course including a recent JNA jar, jna-5.15.0.jar, to my CLASSPATH) I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'getStruct': /home/h3007/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage/af05c638282256cbf9a3f960fefbba02/redhat.java/jdt_ws/hassan-jna-struct_c38993c4/bin/libmycpplib.so: undefined symbol: getStruct
        at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:255)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:618)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:594)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:580)
        at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:248)
        at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0.getStruct(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Main.java:21)

I'm assuming I've done something silly. Apologies, but pointers to my error would be appreciated.

Note that from Java 22 on you can use the standard Foreign Function and Memory APIs

Side note: If you are going to provide a function that returns objects that must be manually managed to the user you should also provide a function that the user can use to release the object. Remember that in C++ there is no automatic garbage collection, so anything you create with new must be given back at some point with delete to prevent memory leakage.

Agreed. The example above was a minimal-ish test, but my subsequent code includes a delete method.

I managed to make your proposal work with command line with two modifications.
First, I had to compile MyStruct.cpp with the -fPIC option:
g++  -shared -o libmycpplib.so MyStruct.cpp -fPIC

Second, you have to be careful in the Main.java file since the type of y should be coherent with the type double in the cpp file:
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Structure.FieldOrder;

public class Main 
{
    public interface MyCppLibrary extends Library 
    {
        MyCppLibrary INSTANCE = (MyCppLibrary) Native.load("mycpplib", MyCppLibrary.class);

        @FieldOrder({"x", "y"})
        class MyStruct extends Structure 
        {
            public int x;
            public double y;
        }

        MyStruct getStruct();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MyCppLibrary lib = MyCppLibrary.INSTANCE;
        MyCppLibrary.MyStruct myStruct = lib.getStruct();

        System.out.println("x: " + myStruct.x);
        System.out.println("y: " + myStruct.y);
    }
}

Then compile and launch with:
javac -classpath /usr/share/java/jna.jar  Main.java
java  -classpath /usr/lib/java/jna.jar:.  Main

Possible output:
x: 10
y: 20.5


Thanks. Apologies I did notice the issue with the type of y shortly after my post and fixed it. Should have updated my question. I didn't need to use the -fPIC switches, but will take that into consideration, thanks.

Apologies, problem was as simple as a missing EOF character to the my_struct.cpp file ! At least the above should work for others interesting in trying out JNA!

A terminating EOF character in a C++ source file does not make the difference between a working and non-working program. Something else is going on here.

OK perhaps you are right. I guess I will try to monitor my code changes carefully to see what is going wrong. I should mention that I'm running the code from VS Code.
